# How to perform a parametrized raw query in Django?

Tags: mysql, django, mariadb

I'm reading the official [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/), but I can't find an answer to my question.

Right now I have this query implemented, working with a custom MariaDB connector for Django:

```
results = []
cursor  = get_cursor()
try:
    sql="SELECT a.*, COALESCE( NULLIF(a.aa, '.'), NULLIF(a.gen, '.') ) AS variant, b.*, c.* FROM `db-dummy`.sp_gen_data c JOIN `db-dummy`.gen_info a ON a.record_id = c.gen_id JOIN `db-dummy`.sp_data b ON b.record_id = c.sp_id WHERE a.gene_name LIKE concat(?, '%') AND a.report_notation LIKE concat('%', ?, '%') AND b.sp_id LIKE concat(?, '%');"
    data = (gen, var, sp)
    cursor.execute(sql, data)
except mariadb.Error as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
results = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))     
return results
```

It works, but now I need to adapt this query to the django's default MySQL backend.

What I've tried:

```
results = []
cursor  = get_cursor()
sql="SELECT a.*, COALESCE( NULLIF(a.aa, '.'), NULLIF(a.gen, '.') ) AS variant, b.*, c.* FROM `db-dummy`.sp_gen_data c JOIN `db-dummy`.gen_info a ON a.record_id = c.gen_id JOIN `db-dummy`.sp_data b ON b.record_id = c.sp_id WHERE a.gene_name LIKE %s AND a.report_notation LIKE %s AND b.sp_id LIKE %s;"
data = ('{}%'.format(gen), '{}%'.format(var), '{}%'.format(sp))
cursor.execute(sql, data)

columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
results = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    results.append(dict(zip(columns, row)))
return results
```

So basically what I had to change to make it work was `LIKE concat(?, '%')` for `LIKE %s`.

The problem is, for the `a.report_notation LIKE concat('%', ?, '%')` part, I do not know how to convert it to something that Django can interpret.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why use a raw query and not the ORM?

Comment: I am not allowed to use ORM in this project.

Comment: Your first query may work with a couple of adjustments: you need to replace `?` with `%s` for passing parameters and you need to replace `%` with `%%` as a single percent is an "escape" character and to include a literal `%` char you need to pass `%%`. [It's in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) - `Note that if you want to include literal percent signs in the query, you have to double them in the case you are passing parameters `

Comment: @IainShelvington Everything works right now except for this part: `a.report_notation LIKE concat('%', ?, '%')` which I don't know how to convert to django parameterized query.

Comment: Wouldn't it be `a.report_notation LIKE concat('%%', %s, '%%')`?

Comment: @IainShelvington That was it, could write an answer so that I can accept your answer?

Comment: sure, added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query should be fine just adjusted to match the format that Django expects.

First, replace `?` with `%s` to pass parameters to the query

Second, replace `%` with `%%` as a single percent is an "escape" character and you need to escape the escape char

[DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

Here's your original query truncated to show an example of how it could work

```
sql="... WHERE a.gene_name LIKE concat(%s, '%%') AND a.report_notation LIKE concat('%%', %s, '%%') AND b.sp_id LIKE concat(%s, '%%');"
data = (gen, var, sp)
cursor.execute(sql, data)
```